# Como evitar que a linha perca a referência da cor no ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, listview

Tenho um ExpandableListView com 5 grupos e cada grupo tem seus filhos(Child). Eu mudei a cor de fundo de alguns filhos, porém quando eu uso o scroll bagunça todas as linhas, pintando tudo. Isso acontece por causa do recycle do listView, quando estou usando um listView simples eu sobrescrevo os métodos `getViewType` e `getViewTypeCount` e resolve meu problema. No expandable possuem os métodos `getChildType` e `getChildTypeCount`, porém não está funcionando. Alguém já trabalhou com estes dois métodos no expandable e pode dar uma ajuda? Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala Daniel,

Coloca seu código aqui, é melhor pra te ajudar.

Mas provavelmente seu problema é que você faz um IF para colorir as linhas né?

Então você precisa colocar um ELSE pra cor padrão, exemplo:

```
if(filho == filho){
   //cor da linha muda
}else{
   //cor da linha padrão
}
```

Isso acontece porque você está usando RecyclerView e como o nome diz, ele recicla as células já usadas pra criar uma nova.

Abraços.

Comment: eu já tinha tido esse problema com listView há muito atrás e essa solução não tinha funcionado, mas com o expandable deu certo. Obrigadão. Abraços.